# Can Silverlight Out-of-Browser app call .NET DLLs?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

This might be a stupid question (I'm new to Silverlight!), but if I develop a .NET DLL with methods, can my Silverlight Out-of-browser app call and use this DLL and its methods if it is provided in the IsolatedStorage area of my Silverlight OOB install? Or does all code have to be contained in the Silverlight package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to: Use Automation in Trusted Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457794%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)