# System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials from Trusted Silverlight App?

Tags: silverlight, elevated-privileges

From here, [Can Silverlight Out-of-Browser app call .NET DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740832/can-silverlight-out-of-browser-app-call-net-dlls), it is possible to call full .NET code from Silverlight, as long as the app is trusted and what you are accessing is ComVisible.

Sadly System.Net.CredentialCache is not ComVisible.

Is there anyway to get the same information?

Comment: Could you create a ComVisible wrapper?

Comment: Yes, I could.  I was hoping there might be something existing in the .NET framework that already is and can return this.

Comment: Return what exactly? You want the `DefaultCredentials` property?

Comment: Yes, the value of the DefaultCredentials property.

Comment: If you are using Silverlight 5 (which allows native windows API), you could call this `CredEnumerate()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374794(v=vs.85).aspx